# In Ephesian 5:27 what does Christ "present to himself"?

Tags: greek, textual-criticism, grammar, referent-identification, ephesians

I was struck with the oddness of a groom "presenting" one's bride "to himself" as it doesn't match our culture where the father of the bride "gives away" his daughter. As I looked at this familiar passage for weddings I also notice that "the assembly" (commonly translated "the Church") is feminine but what he presents to himself is masculine:

> http://biblehub.com/text/ephesians/5-27.htm

And to make it more interesting, rather than being in the accusative it is in the nominative!

Can someone with some Greek skills unpack this and show what Christ presents to himself?

> Westcott and Hort / [NA27 variants] Eph 5:27 ἵνα παραστήσῃ **αὐτὸς** ἑαυτῷ
>   ἔνδοξον τὴν ἐκκλησίαν, μὴ ἔχουσαν σπίλον ἢ ῥυτίδα ἤ τι τῶν τοιούτων,
>   ἀλλ' ἵνα ᾖ ἁγία καὶ ἄμωμος.

Here is the ESV:

> so that he might present the church ["him"] to himself in splendor, without
>   spot or wrinkle or any such thing, that she might be holy and without
>   blemish.

Comment: The Textus Receptus (I am quoting from the Stephens 1550 text) has αυτην, _auten_, which translates to _her_, the [feminine](http://biblehub.com/greek/aute_n_846.htm).

Comment: @NigelJ  Yes, but that manuscript first appeared in 1550 and has very little credibility. NA doesn't seem to register it as a significant variant. http://biblehub.com/text/ephesians/5-27.htm

Comment: There is a 'significant' division regarding the TR and the NA. I was trying to draw attention to the much more sensible feminine as against the nonsensical masculine.

Comment: @NigelJ  I understand and that is fine however, the TR is evidently manhandled and is not significant as textual evidence. There may be other witnesses that are more credible, I don't know.

Comment: I think you have chosen one of the very places which indicates the superiority of the Received Text to the later incorporation of Sinaiticus/Vaticanus. 50 years of following the arguments have not persuaded me to move an inch from the TR.

Comment: @NigelJ  The problem is who is to say if Erasmus didn't make the correction himself in 1550? I am inclined to say that the masculine is a copyist error but what if discounting it we miss something significant?

Comment: @Ruminator: *What if by discounting it we miss something significant ?* - If there is indeed something significant to be missed, it would appear that [Chrysostom](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf113.iii.iv.xxi.html) missed it as well in the fourth century, while writing in Greek.

Comment: I just noticed that in addition to being masculine, it is in the nominative!

Comment: In case if there is αὐτός, it will translate as "in order that he might present to himself a glorified church", but if there is αὐτήν, then it will translate as "in order that he might present it to himself as a glorified church". Both are plausible and convey the same meaning, but I think αὐτήν makes a better sense, for αὐτός makes an apparent redundancy. But I may be mistaken and this emphasis could be of an importance, not yet understandable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

αὐτὸς is not the object "him" but the subject "he" and is usually implied rather than explicit so I take this as an emphasis. Paul is saying that the bride does not prepare herself but rather he prepares his bride:

"so that *he* may present her *to himself* as a glorious assembly without spot or wrinkle".

This connects well with the self-interest he highlights later about "he that loves his wife loves himself".

Disclaimer: I'm not very qualified in Greek so if I'm talking nonsense, please correct. Thanks.